# How to set drop down value using selenium Web driver in java with mozila browser

Tags: java, firefox, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to set value in drop down but unable to set it using **FireFox 47.0.1**, **Webdriver 3.5.1** with Java 8 and Eclipse Luna. This is what I tried :

```
Select selectByValue = new Select(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#dispositionId")));
selectByValue.selectByVisibleText("Warm Pipeline");
```

HTML code:-

```
<select name="dispositionId" onchange="hideShowProductSpan();changeHashMark();setDropDown‌​ToHdnField('disposit‌​ionId','dispNm');set‌​DipCallStatus5();" class="select_m" id="dispositionId"> <option value="">Please Select</option> <option value="1"> Hot Pipeline </option> <option value="2"> Warm Pipeline </option> <option value="2"> Cold Pipeline </option> </select>
```

Comment: Share html or URL

Comment: what issue u are facing

Comment: using above code I am unable to set value in selected drop down

Comment: share URL or Html

Comment: <select name="dispositionId" onchange="hideShowProductSpan();changeHashMark();setDropDownToHdnField('dispositionId','dispNm');setDipCallStatus5();" class="select_m" id="dispositionId">
     <option value="">Please Select</option>
   
         <option value="1">
           Hot Pipeline
         </option>
         <option value="2">
          Warm Pipeline
        </option>
     <option value="2">
      Cold Pipeline
    </option>
  
   </select>

Comment: where is ur html, you forgot to add

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Select selectByValue = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("dispositionId")));
selectByValue.selectByVisibleText("Warm Pipeline");
```

if you have `id` then id first then go for `xpath` and `css`. Your `css` path is also correct. Try to add some `wait` for page load and then try it. But I again suggest you to use `id`

Comment: show me the error log. Please attach snapshot what error u got. Also check is your element in frame. if possible please share URL

Comment: Can u please copy paste your complete post

Comment: I am copy paste ur html in .txt file and save it as html. and then right code for it is working.

Comment: Please give your Code of selenium

Answer (score 0):

Hi this my selenium code go through it

```
    public class UrlCall {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\SeleniumDriver\\geckodriver.exe");
WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://10.0.71.77:5590/ezcss/");
String parent_window=driver.getWindowHandle();
System.out.println("parent_window  "+parent_window);
//driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#login")).sendKeys("IN44355");
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#password")).sendKeys("1");
Thread.sleep(2000);
driver.findElement(By.className("submit_form")).click();
Thread.sleep(2000);
System.out.println("unser if");
driver.findElement(By.className("form-login")).sendKeys("1");
Thread.sleep(5000);
driver.findElement(By.className("login_button")).click();
Thread.sleep(5000);
Set<String> allWindows=driver.getWindowHandles();
int windowSize=allWindows.size();
System.out.println("window size is "+windowSize);
int i=1;
for(String window : allWindows){
    System.out.println("window  "+i+" "+window);
    i++;
    if(!parent_window.equalsIgnoreCase(window)){
        driver.switchTo().window(window);
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        driver.findElement(By.className("select_m")).sendKeys("DELHI");
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        driver.findElement(By.name("menu_city")).sendKeys("DELHI");
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        driver.findElement(By.name("isprofiler.jsp")).click();


        Thread.sleep(2000);
        /*driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#dispositionId")).click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);*/
        driver.findElement(By.id("dispositionId")).click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        Select selectByValue = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("dispositionId")));
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        selectByValue.selectByVisibleText("Warm Pipeline");

        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#alternateno2")).sendKeys("7529925241");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#comments")).sendKeys("Very Interested  to take loan");


    }
        }

Thread.sleep(2000);
  }

   }
```

Comment: seems correct code, But it is sure my code is correct, some other issue is there